# When to choose which participle? — “anstrengend” vs. “angestrengt”

Tags: difference, adjective, past-participle, grammar-identification, participle

How do I choose between two possibilities? Examples:

Why

> Nach vielen anstrengenden Wochen bei der Arbeit

and not

> Nach vielen angestrengten Wochen bei der Arbeit

Another example:

> Ein blondgelocktes kleines Mädchen

instead of

> Ein blondlockendes kleines Mädchen

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally speaking:

- the "*Partizip 1*" forms "*anstrengend*" / "*blondlockend*" assume that the respective subject "*Woche*" / "*Mädchen*" **causes a certain effect** or **exhibits a certain activity**. But this is true only for the case of "*anstrengende Wochen*", it doesn't apply in the latter case. Instead, having blond, curly hair is simply a state. It may be true if you use "*blondlockend*" in a more creative way, as a conscious, **neologistic** composition of "*blond*" and "*lockend*" in the sense of "luring, tempting".
- "*angestrengt*" is a difficult thing. The problem is that [you can't use every verb in its Perfect Participle form as adjective](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Verb/Finit-Infinit/Part2.html#Anchor-Das-49575). "*anstrengen*" (in the sense of "*Die Woche strengt an / ist anstrengend*") is intransitive, since you can't use it in a passive form. Furthermore, it [*is a durative verb, **not a perfective one***](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Verb/Bedeutung/Aktionsart.html#Anchor-Perfektive-35882). It doesn't describe a status change that was finished at a certain moment in the past. Those verbs can't be used in its Partizip Perfekt form.

The problem with "*anstrengen*" is that it may also have a transitive meaning (in the sense of "*einen Prozess anstrengen*" - "to file a suit / to bring a procedure / to pursue an action") - you can speak of a "*Prozess*" who "*wurde angestrengt*" - a "suit that was filed". So, you'll first have to determine the exact sense and its characteristics as transitive / intransitive. Then, you can tell (usually) if you can use it as adjective in its "*Partizip Perfekt*" form.

EDIT: Additionally, here's a nice compilation of rules regarding Partizip 1 and Partizip 2: http://www.dsporto.de/ubungen/partizipregeln.htm (in german, sorry...)

Comment: *Das blond lockende Haarspray*? Im Sinne von »das Haarspray erzeugt, bei richtiger Anwendung, blonde Locken«?

Comment: Wie um Himmels Willen kommst Du jetzt auf Haarspray? Obacht, rhetorische Frage...

Answer (score 3):

I would love to present a different example which gets the point across better, because both participles of that verb can be used more or less idiomaticly on the same noun. The verb I am using is *fahren*.

> Das *fahrende* Mädchen.

As Tohuwawohu pointed out, this is pretty much an active participle. The girl *is driving*. Actively sitting behind the wheel (or on the saddle in the case of a bicycle).

> Das *gefahrene* Mädchen.

Here, the girl is *being driven*. Considering the word choice *Mädchen*, it is likely that she is sitting in the back seat.

Context would further provide what else is happening and why the act of driving/being driven has to be put into a participle.

Comment: Irgendwie hab' ich "das gefallene Mädchen" gelesen...

Comment: @tofro Vielleicht noch schöner; das fallende und das gefallene ;)

Answer (score 1):

Case 1: *Angestrengte Wochen* would mean, that the weeks themselves were strained, which misses the point. The weeks were *straining* to some person, and analogously *anstrengend* is the word to choose.

Case 2: The girl is blonde and has curls. Solution 1 is correct, *blondgelockt* could also be substituted by *blondlockig*. It remains unanswered from this sentence, whether color of hair or its curls are natural or result of styling (even if only the latter strictly justifies the participle). *Lockend* means in the vast majority of cases alluring, tempting. *Blondlockend* surely could theoretically mean "creating blonde curls", but the context does not support this idea and it would need substiantial support due to infavourable statistics.